# Insert array to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to insert array into database. I've form which looks like

```
<form action="" method="post">
<p>servicename</p>
<input type="text" name="service_name"><br>

<p>bgname</p>
<input type='text' name="background[]">
<input type='text' name="background[]">
<input type='text' name="background[]">

<p>bg price:</p>
<input type='text' name="background_price[]">
<input type='text' name="background_price[]">
<input type='text' name="background_price[]">

<p>resolution:</p>
<input type='text' name="resolution[]">
<input type='text' name="resolution[]">

<p>resolution price</p>
<input type='text' name="resolution_price[]">
<input type='text' name="resolution_price[]">

<p>count</p>
<input type='text' name="count[]">
<input type='text' name="count[]">
<input type='text' name="count[]">
<input type='text' name="count[]">
<input type='text' name="count[]">

<p>count price</p>
<input type='text' name="count_price[]">
<input type='text' name="count_price[]">
<input type='text' name="count_price[]">
<input type='text' name="count_price[]">
<input type='text' name="count_price[]">

<p>Type:</p>
<input type='text' name="type[]">
<input type='text' name="type[]">
<input type='text' name="type[]">

<p>Type price</p>
<input type='text' name="type_price[]">
<input type='text' name="type_price[]">
<input type='text' name="type_price[]">

<p>how</p>
<input type='text' name="how[]">
<input type='text' name="how[]">

<p>how price</p>
<input type='text' name="how_price[]">
<input type='text' name="how_price[]">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Also I wrote script which works, but I have too many unnecessary tables and I want to optimize it to one table

```
<?php
class Service extends Connection {
public function addService($service_name, $background, $background_price, $resolution, $resolution_price, $count, $count_price, $type, $type_price, $how, $how_price) {
        try {
            $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO services (id, name) VALUES ('', ?)");
            $sth->bindParam(1, $service_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        foreach($background as $index1 => $backgroundItem) {
            try {
                $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO background (id, service_name, background, background_price) VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?)");
                $sth->bindParam(1, $service_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(2, $backgroundItem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(3, $background_price[$index1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $sth->execute();
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage;
            }
        }

        foreach($resolution as $index2=> $resolutionItem) {
            try {
                $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO resolution (id, service_name, resolution, resolution_price) VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?)");
                $sth->bindParam(1, $service_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(2, $resolutionItem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(3, $resolution_price[$index2], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $sth->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        foreach($count as $index3=> $countItem) {
            try {
                $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO counts (id, service_name, count, count_price) VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?)");
                $sth->bindParam(1, $service_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(2, $countItem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(3, $count_price[$index3], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $sth->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        foreach($type as $index4=> $typeItem) {
            try {
                $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO type (id, service_name, type, type_price) VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?)");
                $sth->bindParam(1, $service_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(2, $typeItem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(3, $type_price[$index4], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $sth->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        foreach($how as $index5=> $howItem) {
            try {
                $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO how (id, service_name, how, how_price) VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?)");
                $sth->bindParam(1, $service_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(2, $howItem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(3, $how_price[$index5], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $sth->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
      }

    }
}
?>
```

How should I do to save array to table 'services' which looks like
    `id | service_name | background | background_price | count | count_price | type | type_price | how | how_price | resolution | resolution_price`
I tried a lot of solutions from Stack but nothing didn't helped me.Regards      [exported schema table 'services'](http://pastebin.com/w77chVsn)

Comment: Ok. So, data is not entering in 'services' table only. Correct. Rest all table working.?

Comment: Yeah, rest table works. Data is not entering in 'services' because I don't know how to push whole array into one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question and what you want to achieve then this is one approach for your problem:

```
class Service extends Connection {
    public function addService($service_name, $background, $background_price, $resolution, $resolution_price, $count, $count_price, $type, $type_price, $how, $how_price) {
        $max = max(count($background), count($background_price), count($resolution), count($resolution_price), count($count), count($count_price), count($type), count($type_price), count($how), count($how_price));

        try {
            $query = "INSERT INTO services (`service_name`, `background`, `background_price`, `count`, `count_price`, `type`, `type_price`, `how`, `how_price`, `resolution`, `resolution_price`) VALUES ";
            $data = [];
            for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
                $query .= "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),";
                $data[] = isset($service_name) ? $service_name : '';
                $data[] = isset($background[$i]) ? $background[$i] : '';
                $data[] = isset($background_price[$i]) ? $background_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[] = isset($count[$i]) ? $count[$i] : '';
                $data[] = isset($count_price[$i]) ? $count_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[] = isset($type[$i]) ? $type[$i] : '';
                $data[] = isset($type_price[$i]) ? $type_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[] = isset($how[$i]) ? $how[$i] : '';
                $data[] = isset($how_price[$i]) ? $how_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[] = isset($resolution[$i]) ? $resolution[$i] : '';
                $data[] = isset($resolution_price[$i]) ? $resolution_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
            }
            $query = rtrim($query, ',');
            $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
            $sth->execute($data);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second approach with single query for every insert:

```
class Service extends Connection {
    public function addService($service_name, $background, $background_price, $resolution, $resolution_price, $count, $count_price, $type, $type_price, $how, $how_price) {
        $max = max(count($background), count($background_price), count($resolution), count($resolution_price), count($count), count($count_price), count($type), count($type_price), count($how), count($how_price));

        try {
            $query = "INSERT INTO services (`service_name`, `background`, `background_price`, `count`, `count_price`, `type`, `type_price`, `how`, `how_price`, `resolution`, `resolution_price`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
                $data = [];
                $data[] = isset($service_name) ? $service_name : '';
                $data[] = isset($background[$i]) ? $background[$i] : '';
                $data[] = isset($background_price[$i]) ? $background_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[] = isset($count[$i]) ? $count[$i] : '';
                $data[] = isset($count_price[$i]) ? $count_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[] = isset($type[$i]) ? $type[$i] : '';
                $data[] = isset($type_price[$i]) ? $type_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[] = isset($how[$i]) ? $how[$i] : '';
                $data[] = isset($how_price[$i]) ? $how_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[] = isset($resolution[$i]) ? $resolution[$i] : '';
                $data[] = isset($resolution_price[$i]) ? $resolution_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type

                $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
                $sth->execute($data);
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

And for `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` when duplicate row is found:

```
class Service extends Connection {
    public function addService($service_name, $background, $background_price, $resolution, $resolution_price, $count, $count_price, $type, $type_price, $how, $how_price) {
        $max = max(count($background), count($background_price), count($resolution), count($resolution_price), count($count), count($count_price), count($type), count($type_price), count($how), count($how_price));

        try {
            $query = "INSERT INTO services (`service_name`, `background`, `background_price`, `count`, `count_price`, `type`, `type_price`, `how`, `how_price`, `resolution`, `resolution_price`) VALUES
                        (:service_name, :background,:background_price,:count,:count_price,:type,:type_price,:how,:how_price,:resolution,:resolution_price)
                      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                        `background`=:background2, `background_price`=:background_price2, `count`=:count2, `count_price`=:count_price2,
                        `type`=:type2, `type_price`=:type_price2, `how`=:how2, `how_price`=:how_price2, `resolution`=:resolution2, `resolution_price`=:resolution_price2";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
                $data = [];
                $data[':service_name'] = isset($service_name) ? $service_name : '';
                $data[':background'] = isset($background[$i]) ? $background[$i] : '';
                $data[':background2'] = isset($background[$i]) ? $background[$i] : '';
                $data[':background_price'] = isset($background_price[$i]) ? $background_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[':background_price2'] = isset($background_price[$i]) ? $background_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[':count'] = isset($count[$i]) ? $count[$i] : '';
                $data[':count2'] = isset($count[$i]) ? $count[$i] : '';
                $data[':count_price'] = isset($count_price[$i]) ? $count_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[':count_price2'] = isset($count_price[$i]) ? $count_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[':type'] = isset($type[$i]) ? $type[$i] : '';
                $data[':type2'] = isset($type[$i]) ? $type[$i] : '';
                $data[':type_price'] = isset($type_price[$i]) ? $type_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[':type_price2'] = isset($type_price[$i]) ? $type_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[':how'] = isset($how[$i]) ? $how[$i] : '';
                $data[':how2'] = isset($how[$i]) ? $how[$i] : '';
                $data[':how_price'] = isset($how_price[$i]) ? $how_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[':how_price2'] = isset($how_price[$i]) ? $how_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[':resolution'] = isset($resolution[$i]) ? $resolution[$i] : '';
                $data[':resolution2'] = isset($resolution[$i]) ? $resolution[$i] : '';
                $data[':resolution_price'] = isset($resolution_price[$i]) ? $resolution_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type
                $data[':resolution_price2'] = isset($resolution_price[$i]) ? $resolution_price[$i] : 0; // OR '' depending on the column type

                $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
                $sth->execute($data);
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I get  `Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in B:\xampp\htdocs\bang\class\service.php on line 25`

Comment: btw. I changed `$data[] = isset($service_name[$i]) ? $service_name[$i] : '';` on `$data[] = isset($service_name) ? $service_name : '';` because `$service_name` isn't array. Also I removed max() for this variable.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I forgot to add '.' in the `$query .= "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),"`. Answer updated.

Comment: I fixed this line, this helped in small part - doesn't display any errors neither doesn't add any data to database. `var_dump()` is working fine so something must be wrong with query I guess. I have added `id` column, but this didn't helped.

Comment: can you add var_dump of query and data after the for loop ?

Comment: Yeah I can. I'll send you output in a sec.

Comment: I need var_dump($data) also

Comment: Did you copy my last edit of the answer? Because in the var_dump of the $query the comma is missing

Comment: Yeah, I have copied `$query .= "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),";`

Comment: Ok but in the first link with dumps for the query, the comma separator is missing in the dump?

Comment: I uploaded var_dump of the $query without without comma, sorry for that, but comma is exists and still doesn't work

Comment: Here is current var_dump with comma [current var_dump($query)](http://pastebin.com/ttnGUeSd)

Comment: Did you add Primary Key and auto increment on id column in services table ?

Comment: UNIQUE/PRIMARY i didn't remember. AI is on.

Comment: I'll delete and create `id` column one more time

Comment: and after that put the exported schema of the table in your question

Comment: primary/ai and still nothing

Comment: you have varchar and int columns in your table, but all the data in $data is string? You rather change the data or change column types to varchar. For example you have "resolution price 1" as value for resolution price

Comment: I have set every columns as varchar and still nothing

Comment: oh you have a unique key on servic_name column. You should provide unique values for it in the data you are passing to the query

Comment: try with the second approach

Comment: How I should write query if I want to: insert data if doesn't exists, update if exists? (this same table `services` and form)

Comment: Update doesn't work as should. If I don't change any input and just press 'submit' - works, doesn't duplicate data, but If I change value of input e.g `background[]` then adds new row `background[]` but also duplicate other inputs like `resolution[]`, `resolution_price[]` etc

Comment: I tried `UPDATE services SET ...`. If I will change input value - it's works, no duplications, but If I'll add next input (angular) then table data is broken. I got a lot of 0's in rows. So how well mix `UPDATE` and `INSERT`?

Comment: Only `id` column is primary

Comment: Duplicate works only if you have unique key and the insert tries to insert value for that column (with the unique key) that already exists. For example if you add unique key to service_name then only one insert will pass with service_name='test'. If you try to insert another entry with service_name='test' - then update will be triggered.

Comment: Okay, I have set `UNIQUE` for every column pose `service_name`. If I'll add next inputs (angular as I said before) this works. In database I got `id 2` with data which I typed in inputs, but If I'll add next inputs `id 2` is updated instead add next row in table with `id 3` [preview form](http://i.imgur.com/FErqAMp.png)

Comment: If id=2 has service_name='ABC' and you don`t change service_name in the inputs then normally you will have update instead of insert (as long as service_name exists in the table already)

Comment: Now I see, If I'll add more inputs than exists ID, then something works as shouldn't

Comment: And also I see next fault. When I've set `UNIQUE` for columns I can't type same e.g `background` for other `service_name`. I'm exhausted.